# How do I set the parent's rotation to the child's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, parent

I am new to unity and C# as a whole and don't quite know how to do this it would be very great if you could help me with this.

Thank you!

What I have tried:

I tried storing the rotation with quaternions but I couldn't get it to work and do not know what to do.

Comment: Work with the transformation matrices directly. This makes it easy to store them and to apply consistent effects across different items. My experience is that other approaches get very messy very quickly once you go beyond an individual transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now - understood your title the opposite way at first ^^

So if I understand correctly you have two objects

```
- Parent
  | - Child
```

and you want

- If `Child` is rotated
- `Parent` should apply the same rotation
- But without further manipulating `Child`'s rotation or position

There are probably multiple ways to achieve this.

First a hacky way:

- unparent `Child`

  ```
  // will maintain current absolute world space transforms
  Child.transform.SetParent(null);
  ```
- copy rotation into parent

  ```
  Parent.transform.rotation = Child.transform.rotation;
  ```
- parent `Child` back again

  ```
  Child.transform.SetParent(Parent.transform);
  ```

However, this alternates the hierarchy and might not be desired in some cases - you could go around it by additionally store and reset the original `siblingIndex`.

Another similar way:

- store the absolute world position of `Child` (because when rotating the parent it might change otherwise)

  ```
  var childPosition = Child.transform.position;
  ```
- simply copy the rotation in absolute world space

  ```
  Parent.transform.rotation = Child.transform.rotation;
  ```
- reset the `Child`'s **local** offset rotation

  ```
  Child.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.idendity;
  ```
- reset the `Child`'s absolute world space position

  ```
  Child.transform.position = childPosition;
  ```

I would probably prefer the second in order to not cause issues with the hierarchy.

---

Little demo

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Parent;
    public Transform Child;

    public enum Option
    {
        FirstApproach,
        SecondApproach
    }

    public Option UseApproach;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        switch (UseApproach)
        {
            case Option.FirstApproach:
                Child.SetParent(null);
                Parent.rotation = Child.rotation;
                Child.SetParent(Parent);
                break;
            
            case Option.SecondApproach:
                var childPosition = Child.position;
                Parent.rotation = Child.rotation;
                Child.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Child.position = childPosition;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The parenting system is designed so that the transform of the sub-set objects is affected by the parent object. If you don't want part of it like rotation. or it is going to be transferred to another object. I suggest that you use **Constraints**.

---

In the first step, consider an empty root for the center of rotation of both objects, and then use a rotation constraint to make the parent object imitate the child.

[image: Root Structure]

Rotation Constraint in Parent:

[image: Rotation Constraint]

Result:

[image: Result]