# How to position a parent gameObject where it's child is in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an Enemy AI using some animations that I found and root motion. I have a parent gameObject which has a few child gameObjects, including the 3D model of the enemy. I have attached my animator in this Enemy 3D model and now, for example, when the walking animation is triggered, since it's using root motion, the child element walks towards the player, which is what is supposed to happen visually, however, the parent gameObject isn't affected at all, making it confusing for the other scripts and not working correctly.

This only changes the child's transform and here comes my question - how can I rotate and position the parent object, on top of the child one. So, when the child gameObject moves or is rotated, the same would happen to it's parent.

[image]

I thought of a solution to make the 3D model as a parent and move all the child gameObjects into that 3D model, which probably would solve the issue (hopefully without creating another one), but I am really curious if there is an answer to my question.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, but maybe you can copy the Animator gameObject to the parent. But as you mentioned, this will animate all children of that parent gameObject

Comment: Well to make it simpler - I need to move the parent on top of the child on each frame. So, wherever the child is, thats where the parent would position as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752932/how-do-i-set-the-parents-rotation-to-the-childs-rotation/75753413#75753413).

Imho the best way would probably be to not use parenting here at all but maybe introduce a meta lay like from

```
 - Parent
   |- Child
```

go to

```
 - Controller
   |- Parent
   |- Child
```

and then on the Controller (which doesn't move at all ever) simply do

```
Parent.transform.position = Child.transform.position;
Parent.transform.rotation = Child.transform.rotation;
```

without needing to care about the hierarchy nesting at all.

---

If this is not an option though you still can go with the linked (almost) duplicate, except you also want to copy over the position.

In the first hacky way you would simply do accordingly

```
// will maintain current absolute world space transforms
Child.transform.SetParent(null);
// copy the values to the parent while the child is detached
Parent.transform.rotation = Child.transform.rotation;
Parent.transform.position = Child.transform.position;
// parent back
Child.transform.SetParent(Parent.transform);
// + if required might need to carry over siblingIndex as well
```

In the second (preferred) way without modifying the hierarchy you could do accordingly

```
// simply copy over the absolute transforms -> This will move the child along
Parent.transform.position = Child.transform.position;
Parent.transform.rotation = Child.transform.rotation;
// then reset the childs local offset since supposedly the parent objects transforms match with the childs one now anyway
Child.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.idendity;
Child.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```